# Erro 1064 MySql Workbench

Tags: mysql, sql

sou estudante de Analise e Desenvolvimento de sistemas, e estou tendo problema com a criação do script abaixo:

[image: erro select]

o erro apresentado é o seguinte:

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 7

[image: erro no select]
e também aparece a seguinte mensagem quando posiciono o custo sobre o select.

print da alteração sugerida aqui no fórum.
[image: alter]

Porém o erro persiste.

Comment: Faltou o BEGIN / END.

Comment: Inseri o BEGIN uma linha acima do SELECT e o  END após  a última linha, mas o erro persiste com o select sublinhado em vermelho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece que os parênteses estão desbalanceados nas condições do filtro. Tente

```sql
select avg(fn_media(NotaP1, NotaP2))
as "Media Exame"
from notas
wherer DisciplinaId = Var_DisciplinaId
and (fn_media(NotaP1, NotaP2)) >= 4.0
and (fn_media(NotaP1, NotaP2)) <= 6.9
```

Comment: excelente, estas coisas cegam a gente, rsrsrsr, problema resolvido, eram só os parenteses.